# CS0103: The name does not exist in the current context dev to webserver issue

Tags: asp.net

I have created a few classes that operate separately from the normal aspx.cs files.  When I added a new class I was prompted to add these to app_data, i did.  So I copied out these files and the app_data folder and it cannot be found.  I tried the .cs files at the root of the website and they still could not be found.

I'm sure i'm messing up on a common mistake.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They need to be in the App_Code folder.